# How do I find the length of a sound generated by pyttsx3

Tags: python-3.x, pyttsx, mutagen

I am making a program that needs the length of speech generated by pyttsx3

I did not find any way to do it using pyttsx3 so I am storing the speech in a file
and then trying to use mutagen to get the audio info

```py
import pyttsx3
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3

# the engine
engine = pyttsx3.init()

# 'Hello World' is just an example
engine.save_to_file('Hello world', 'test.mp3')
engine.runAndWait()

# load the mp3 as an audio
audio = MP3('test.mp3')
# the line above gives an error
```

I get the following error `mutagen.mp3.HeaderNotFoundError: can't sync to mpeg frame`

Why am I getting this error?
and also is there any other way to get the length of a pyttsx generated speech?

Answer (score 4):

If there is no specific need to use `mutagen`, I recommend using `pydub` instead. Code below which gives duration in seconds

Code:

```py
import pyttsx3
from pydub import AudioSegment

# the engine
engine = pyttsx3.init()

# 'Hello World' is just an example
engine.save_to_file('Hello world', 'test.mp3')
engine.runAndWait()

# load the mp3 as an audio
audio = AudioSegment.from_file("test.mp3")
print(audio.duration_seconds)
```

Output:

```
0.9205442176870748
```

Comment: Thanks it worked for me :), but don't we need to install ffprobe before pydub?

Comment: I'm using a conda environment and haven't had to do this before. Just a ```pip install pydub``` or a ```conda install pydub``` is usually sufficient.